# SQL query issue for a many to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table structure:

Table `Sailor`:

```
sid    sname
-------------------
22     Dustin
29     Brutus
31     Luber 
32     John
```

Table `Boat`:

```
bid    bname
-------------------
101    Pirate
102    Pirate
103    Marine
```

Table `Reserve`:

```
bid   sid   day
------------------------------
101   22    10/10/98
102   22    10/10/98
103   22    10/8/98
103   31    10/7/98
102   29    9/8/98 
103   32    9/8/98
```

The result expected is: find names of all sailors who have reserved all boats called `Pirate`.

Basically, I need to query all the sailors name who have reserved boat called `Pirate`.

The only issue is that in table boat I have 2 column that has bname as Pirate and their bid are different.

Any idea how to achieve it with the query?

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output based on that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, your dates are ambiguous.  Please use YYYY-MM-DD (or YYYYMMDD) format.

Anyway, here is one way:

```
select b.bid,b.bname,s.sid,s.sname,r.day
  from Boat b join Reserve r on b.bid = r.bid
  join Sailor s on r.sid = s.sid
  where b.bname = 'Pirate';
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are looking for a join operation:

```
SELECT S.* FROM Sailor S JOIN Res R ON S.sid = R.sid 
JOIN Boat B on R.bid = B.bid where B.bname = 'Pirate'
```

Hope it helps